# PHP:login and logout session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am a beginer in php.I am using  PHP-3.I have tried to create login session in php but couldn't succeed.I want to know the entire codes required to create a session such as,login.php,wellcome.php,lock.php,logout.php.Can any one help me?

Comment: "I am using PHP-3" --- O_o Just to be clear - what year is on calendar in where you're currently writing from?

Comment: You want entire code!!!! sorry dude you should not ask like that.You are not our boss.We are here to help those pepople who stuck in between in their code,who show some effort in their code.

Comment: You write "simple code" but don't know this code yourself? First of all, we're in year 2012, we don't use PHP3 anymore. We use PHP5.4.  Second, your comment was very rude. If you want help, be more appreciating. Third: StackOverflow is for helping people with problems, not people who say: "I don't know anything about it, just do it for me". When you want to create a login in php, just read some tutorials and try for yourself and when you THAN have problems, come back again.

Comment: PHP-3 hey? I'll help you... for 3 pound, 10 shilling and tuppence.

Comment: "If you don't know the simple codes it's okay....,i'll go to other visiters better than you" --- lol, it doesn't work nowadays PS: it was not polite at all

Answer (score 5):

My grandfather told me that they used to have something called `phplib` back in the good old days.

Answer (score 2):

visit this pages

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=136

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=137

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=138

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=139

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=140

Answer (score 2):

I think your not starting session before using it go through this -

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

And my suggestion is that use PHP5 & above.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very generic to answer.You can find many tutorials related to this and post if you have specific issues.Hardly anyone could post the entire code over here.

For login and sessions you will need to learn about $_SESSION in PHP.Documented extensively at [php.net](http://php.net).
You will also need a database to store your username and password's -> Mysql is very good to start with.
Also,login logout involves user critical information so you will need MD5 like functions in php to secure your passwords.

Try working on this and here's a link for reference http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-for-Beginners-by-a-Beginners/1/

Hope it helps
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

***Simple PHP Login Script*** 
including session management.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

from [here](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html).

Comment: are you using the same script ? its popular post you know ? tuff to identify till we know what you are doing in script /code.